# How to make an auto button call jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There is a loop that outputs data from the database. There is a form in which there is a `checkbox`, how to make the click on the `checkbox` trigger the `button` click, and then "button" already transfers our data.

The question is in auto clicking on the `button` if we clicked on the `checkbox` by id(so if `checkbox` `id=77`, then `button` with `id=77` will automaticly clicked).

I tried to do something like this, (three forms duplicated for example)

```js
$("form input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
 var value2 =   $(this).attr("id");
  $('form button[id='value2']').trigger('click');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>  
 <?foreach ($table as $rows) {?>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <form method="post" action="eventcheck.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="77">
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
               </label>
               <input hidden="text" name="id" value="<?=$rows['id']?>" />
               <button hidden="submit" name="do_checkbox" id="77"></button></form>
 </td>   
  <td>
 <form method="post" action="eventcheck.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="78">
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
               </label>
               <input hidden="text" name="id" value="<?=$rows['id']?>" />
               <button hidden="submit" name="do_checkbox" id="78"></button></form>
 </td> 
 <td>
  <form method="post" action="eventcheck.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="79">
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
               </label>
               <input hidden="text" name="id" value="<?=$rows['id']?>" />
               <button hidden="submit" name="do_checkbox" id="79"></button></form>
 </td> 
</tr>
 <?}?>
</tbody>         
</table>
```

but of course it doesn't work, how to correct js?

Comment: You really shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. Your code needs to be refactored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using ES6, you could do ->

```
$(`form button[id=${value2}]`).trigger('click');
```

else

```
$("form button[id=" + value2 +"]").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this line `$('form button[id='value2']')`

Comment: You should explain what the bug is and how to fix it.